# jquery multiple textbox with datepicker on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

i can able to display multiple text box using jquery .
now i want to append the datepicker for that text box.
 kindly help me out to get solution 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/yvck28fc/

```js
$('body').append(`<input type="text" id="datepicker">`);
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

First I appended a `input textbox` then assign a `datepicker` to it.
I've used `jQuery datepicker`

Reference: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Hope this will help you.